# Last row displayed using Master/Detail rows breaks the page

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AG Grid React and have run into an issue when using Master/Detail rows, where all rows render and toggle the child rows data fine, but the last row always throws the below error:

```
AG Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, e.g. instead of api.redrawRows(), call setTimeout(function() { api.redrawRows(); }, 0). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.
```

I've followed the instruction to add `setTimeout(function() { api.redrawRows(); }, 0)`, but it make no difference and the page still errors. I've tried componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and also calling it in various custom functions.

I have the detail rows defined in state using the following:

```
detailCellRendererParams: {
      detailGridOptions: {
        columnDefs: [
          {
            headerName: "Consignment Reference",
            field: "consignmentRef",
            cellRenderer: (params) => params.data.consignmentRef || "-",
          },
          {
            headerName: "Shipping Method",
            field: "shippingMethod",
            cellRenderer: (params) => params.data.shippingMethod || "-",
          },
          {
            headerName: "Service",
            field: "suggestedServiceName",
            cellRenderer: (params) => params.data.suggestedServiceName || "-",
          },
          {
            headerName: "Courier",
            field: "courierName",
            cellRenderer: (params) => params.data.courierName || "-",
          },
          {
            headerName: "Tracking Number",
            field: "trackingNo",
            filter: true,
            cellRenderer: (params) =>
              params.data.trackingNo ? (
                <a
                  href={params.data.trackingUrl}
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noreferrer"
                >
                  {params.data.trackingNo}
                </a>
              ) : (
                "-"
              ),
          },
          {
            headerName: "Tracking Status",
            field: "deliveryTrackingStatus",
            cellRenderer: (params) => params.data.deliveryTrackingStatus || "-",
          },
        ],
        defaultColDef: {
          flex: 1,
        },
      },
      getDetailRowData: (params) => {
        const consignments = params.data.consignments;
        if (consignments) {
          params.successCallback(consignments, consignments.length);
        } else {
          params.successCallback([], 0);
        }
      },
    },
```

AG Grid Component:

```
<AgGridReact
                      ref={this.state.gridRef} // Ref for accessing Grid's API
                      masterDetail={true}
                      isRowMaster={(dataItem) => {
                        return dataItem
                          ? dataItem.consignments.length > 0
                          : false;
                      }}
                      detailCellRendererParams={
                        this.state.detailCellRendererParams
                      }
                      pagination={false}
                      groupAllowUnbalanced={true}
                      rowData={this.state.orders}
                      columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                      defaultColDef={{
                        // DefaultColDef sets props common to all Columns
                        sortable: true,
                      }}
                      animateRows={true} // rows animate when sorted
                      onGridReady={() => {
                        this.setState({ gridReady: true });
                        this.state.gridRef.current?.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                      }}
                      groupDisplayType={"groupRows"}
                      gridOptions={{
                        suppressRowHoverHighlight: true,
                      }}
                    />
```

**Stacktrace**

```
ERROR
AG Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, e.g. instead of api.redrawRows(), call setTimeout(function() { api.redrawRows(); }, 0). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.
    at RowRenderer.getLockOnRefresh (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46806:13)
    at RowRenderer.redrawAfterModelUpdate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46750:10)
    at RowRenderer.onPageLoaded (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46627:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7457:11
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at processEventListeners (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7451:24)
    at EventService.dispatchToListeners (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7464:7)
    at EventService.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7431:10)
    at PaginationProxy.onModelUpdated (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48372:23)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7457:11
```

I'm new to using AG Grid so if anyone has experienced anything like this before or theres things missing from the code that might help, please let me know.

Comment: "this stacktrace" 
Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @Val i've updated the above with the stacktrace.